# replace the last occurance of a string in a file

Tags: regex, shell, search, awk, sed

Here's what my file looks like

```
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
```

Those commands are  dynamically generated. What I want is to look for the last Command and make it run in the foreground like this

```
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1
```

The & should be knocked off the last command. 
Any idea how this is done. 
*actually I prolly need a wait inserted also before the last occurrence of gottogohome command. Could some one pl that one too  .*
TY 
Sam

Comment: Is that really what you want to do? Because it won't make your script wait till all processes finish. Maybe you actually mean to leave the last one in the background but add a "wait" as the very last line to wait for all processes to finish...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use tac with awk:

```
tac file | awk '!done && /Gottagohome saab 90 75n/{done=1; sub(/&$/, "")}1' | tac
```

Comment: I'm keen to learn why an awk guru such as your good self would write that. Why wouldn't you write "tac file | awk 'NR==1{sub...}' | tac"? Genuinely intrigued, not critical :-)

Comment: If I had to use `NR==1` I could have just used `tail -1 file |  sed or awk` I wrote it with the flexibility that `comment to be replaced` may or may not be present in the last line. There can be some blank lines/commented lines/some other command present in the input file. My command replaced **last occurrence** of the given command. Hope you understand my viewpoint now.

Comment: Oh ok, very thoughtful of you! I guess I was assuming that the example the OP posted was full and complete and that the last line was the last command - but that was maybe not the best assumption. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: You're most welcome. May be this flexibility wasn't needed by OP but I just looked at this requirement `What I want is to look for the last Command and make it run in the foreground` so implemented it that way.

Comment: Anubhava - standing by your name. You have the 'experience' to insight requirements - that is precisely my situation- there are a lot of other paraphernalia behind that last command.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I am pleased to know that my interpretation wasn't off the mark. (Which means most of other answer won't work).

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$s/.$//' file
```

EDIT:

To cater for *last Command*:

```
sed -r '/(Gottagohome saab 90 75n.*)&\s*$/M,$!b;//{x;//p;x;h};//!H;$!d;x;s//\1/' file
```

Comment: maybe a little security with sed --posix '$s/\$[[:blank:]]*$//' YourFile

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{sub(/&$/,"")}1' file
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

To just remove the last  `&` with `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<NR;i++) print;NF-=1;print}' OFS="" FS="" file
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1&
Gottagohome saab 90 75n > homelog 2>&1
```

Another version

```
awk 'NR>1 {print f}{f=$0} END {print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^Gotta/) a=NR;next} {if (FNR==a) sub(/&$/,"")}1' file file
```